# Getting next className from elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an example block of html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item first">...</div>
  <div class="item second">...</div>
  <div class="item third">...</div>
  <div class="item fourth">...</div>
</div>
```

I want to run through the block and get each items current class and also the class of the next item, here's what I'm trying but `this.nextSibling.className` is always `undefined`:

```
$(".container > .item").each(function(){
  var context = $(this);
  context.text("this is " + this.className + ' next one is ' + this.nextSibling.className);
});
```

How can I do this?

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1y6do3bk/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next sibling is the white space filled text node *between* the divs, not the next div.

Use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling) or jQuery's [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the `nextSibling` in your code is a `textNode` which doesn't have `className` property. You should use `nextElementSibling` or jQuery  `next` method.

```
this.nextElementSibling.className;
context.next().prop('className');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use clicked elements context along with jquery `.next()` to target the next element in each iteration:

```
$(".container > .item").each(function(){
  var context = $(this);
  context.text("this is " + $(this).attr('class') + ' next one is ' + $(this).next().attr('class'));
});
```

### Working Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can use next() function:
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/farhans/z1s4tLoq/)

```
$(".container > .item").each(function(){
        var context = $(this);
        context.text("this is " + this.className + ' next one is ' + context.next().attr('class'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code

```
$(".container > .item").each(function(){
            var context = $(this);
            var nextClassName = $(this).next().attr('class');
            context.text("this is '" + this.className + "' next one is '" + nextClassName +"'");
        });
```

Updated JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1y6do3bk/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".container > .item").each(function(){
        var context = $(this);
        context.text("this is '" + this.className + "' next one is '" + context.next().attr('class') +"'");
    });
```

The last one still comes up as 'undefined' buts that's to be expected...